# Re-run doctrine migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I can I make a doctrine migration re-run in the server without having to access it through SSH to erase the migration on the DB?

If I change the name of the migration file will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to do this according to the Doctrine documentation. But yes, one way to do this would be to re-name the migration file, though that will result in a warning (which you can ignore) that there are migrations for which no class exists.